# How to create an object related with another object on lightning-record-form

Tags: javascript, salesforce, web-component, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to finish a process I've made using a Lightning Web Component.

Essentially, there are 3 main objects here: Event, Visit Comment and Product.

When a user wants to create a visit comment, they go to the Event page and they press a button which opens up a pop-up modal that they can fill with the necessary data to create the visit comment related to that Event. This was achieved using a lightning-record-form and works just fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S5gu.png)

Following this, when the user presses the "Save" button, the record is created and shown in a lighting-datatable on the Event Page.

It's expected, that when the user presses the "Save" button, it also opens up a new modal (similar to the previous one), were users can add products related to the visit comment they just created on the previous modal.

Basically, This process starts with the creation of a record of an object, the "Visit Comment" and ends with the creation of one/more records of another object "Product", that's related to the visit comment previously created.

My problem here is that i don't know how to specify the "id" of the visit comment that was created initially, in the first modal and send it to the second one.

Since the first modal got his event Id from the record page the user is currently viewing, how can i get the visit comment id and send it to the next modal so that the user can add products to that visit comment, even tho he's still on the event page.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Visit Comments related to this Event's Doctor"> 

        <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="New Visit Comment" 
        onclick={customShowModalPopup} slot="actions">     
        </lightning-button> 
        <!-- <break></break> -->
    
        <lightning-datatable
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            key-field="id"
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            hide-checkbox-column="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
    
    </lightning-card>

    <template if:true={customFormModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
              </button>
              <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">New Visit Comment</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <lightning-record-form
                object-api-name={visitCommentObject}
                fields={myFields}
                record-id={visitCommentRecordId}
                onsuccess={handleVisitCommentCreated}
                oncancel={customHideModalPopup}>
            </lightning-record-form>
                 
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
          </template>

          <template if:true={customFormModalProduct}>

            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                    <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                      <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Add Products</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-2">
                    <lightning-record-form
                    object-api-name={productObject}
                    fields={myFieldsProduct}           
                    onsuccess={handleProductCreated}
                    oncancel={customHideModalPopupProduct}>
                </lightning-record-form>
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
              <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
              
          </template>
</template>
```

JS (discarded some unnecessary code related to the lightning-datatable):

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire} from 'lwc';
//import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getVisitCommentList from '@salesforce/apex/datatableWithRowsSelectionVisitComment.getVisitCommentList';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import VISITCOMMENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c.Name';
import INDIVIDUAL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c.Individual__c';
import DATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c.Date__c';
import LOCATION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c.Location__c';
import COMMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/VisitComment__c.Comments__c';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/AddedProduct__c';
import PRODUCTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AddedProduct__c.Product__c';
import PRIORITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AddedProduct__c.Priority__c';
import REACTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AddedProduct__c.Reaction__c';
import PRESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AddedProduct__c.Prescription__c';
import getSingleVisitComment from '@salesforce/apex/datatableWithRowsSelectionVisitComment.getSingleVisitComment';

const actions= [
    { label : 'View', name : 'view' },
    { label : 'Delete', name : 'delete' }
];

const columns= [
    { label : 'Visit Comment Name', fieldName : 'Name' },
    { label : 'Date', fieldName : 'Date__c' },
    { label : 'Comments', fieldName : 'Comments__c' },
    {
        type : 'action',
        typeAttributes : { rowActions : actions }
    }
];
 
export default class DatatableVisitComment extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {


    visitCommentObject = VISITCOMMENT_OBJECT;
    productObject= PRODUCT_OBJECT;

    myFields = [NAME_FIELD, INDIVIDUAL_FIELD, DATE_FIELD, LOCATION_FIELD, COMMENT_FIELD];
   myFieldsProduct =[PRODUCTNAME_FIELD, PRIORITY_FIELD, REACTION_FIELD, PRESCRIPTION_FIELD];

    columns = columns;

    @track data = [];
    @api recordId;    //stores current page Id 
    @api objectApiName;
    @track customFormModal = false;
    @track customFormModalProduct = false;
    
    refreshTable;

    @wire(getVisitCommentList, { lwcRecordId: '$recordId'  })
    relations(result) {
        this.refreshTable = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = result.data;
            this.emptyList = true;
        }
    }

    }

     //Open the Modal
    customShowModalPopup() {            
        this.customFormModal = true;
    }

    //Close the Modal
    customHideModalPopup() {    
        this.customFormModal = false;
    }

    // Close the Modal and refresh datatable data after Visit Comment is inserted
    handleVisitCommentCreated(){

        this.customHideModalPopup();
        
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record Inserted',
                variant: 'success'
            }),
        );  

          
        this.handleAddProduct(); //  METHOD TO OPEN UP PRODUCT MODAL

        debugger;
      

        return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);

      
        
    }

    handleAddProduct(){

     
    this.customFormModalProduct = true;

    }
    
}
```

The handleAddProduct() method is opening up the modal but i don't know how to specify the Visit Comment Id so the product record, when created, becomes related to the visit comment previously created.

Is there's any way to send the Id of a record just created in a modal to another modal?

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your onsuccess (`handleVisitCommentCreated`) is currently without any parameters. SF sends you something but you ignore it.If you change it to accept 1 variable say "event", you'll be able to get the created record's id as "event.detail.id". Store it in `this.commentId` or something and then use in 2nd popup.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation
re-read the "Creating a Record"

It's... not a good design. You risk creating "widows", parent records (comments) without child products. Maybe user cancels out and never adds them, maybe there are errors when creating products... A bit more "pro" move would be to have a complex form but just 1 save button. And pass all data to Apex and create both in 1 go, 1 all-or-nothing transaction.